# AWS SageMaker - In Domains with AWS SSO enabled, both the SingleSignOnIdentifierTypeString and SingleSignOnIdentifierValue fields are required

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to create a new Domain in AWS SageMaker. My domain uses SSO to authenticate and uses a VPC. The domain is created, but an error appears at the top:

```
In Domains with AWS SSO enabled, both the SingleSignOnIdentifierTypeString and SingleSignOnIdentifierValue fields are required.
```

The AWS doc does not mention anything about this type of error.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to assign users as well? When creating user profiles in SSO mode, the API call expects the two specified values. You can also run a DescribeDomain API call and as long as it is in service, you're good to go.